# I want to fork a repo, add a feature and keep syncing with original repo

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub project, I have forked it now I know I can add a feature to it, but how do I keep syncing with the original project time to time

Will git remote originalurl.project and then git pull will help?

Comment: Yes, pulling from the original repo should help.

Comment: Do you know any command by which I differentiate the repo url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type git remote -v and press Enter. You'll see the current configured remote repository for your fork.

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (push)
```

Type git remote add upstream, and then paste the URL you copied in Step 2 and press Enter. It will look like this:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.git
```

To verify the new upstream repository you've specified for your fork, type git remote -v again. You should see the URL for your fork as origin, and the URL for the original repository as upstream.

```
git remote -v
origin    https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (fetch)
origin    https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (push)
upstream  https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
upstream  https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

Now, you can keep your fork synced with the upstream repository with a few Git commands. For more information, see "Syncing a fork."

from https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/

Comment: HI yausername, thanx for this details and its indeed helpful - but yet its a bit half information. The link also says exactly what you have shown above. I would like to know how can I pull from Original repo and from forked repo ?

Comment: for example the git pull command will have some difference when pulling from upstream and origin ..right

Comment: got it - https://help.github.com/articles/merging-an-upstream-repository-into-your-fork/

Comment: git pull upstream master